Installing Griddb Python client vs. 0.8.5 on Windows WSL
I’m running Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL) to run GridDB. I’m trying to install the Python client, version 0.8.5, available here, following the instructions from GridDB Docs, available here.
However, when I run the make command I get the following error:
$ cd python_client-0.8.5
$ make

g++ -fPIC -std=c++0x -g -O2 -c -o src/TimeSeriesProperties.o -Iinclude -Isrc src/TimeSeriesProperties.cpp
g++ -fPIC -std=c++0x -g -O2 -c -o src/ContainerInfo.o -Iinclude -Isrc src/ContainerInfo.cpp
g++ -fPIC -std=c++0x -g -O2 -c -o src/AggregationResult.o -Iinclude -Isrc src/AggregationResult.cpp
g++ -fPIC -std=c++0x -g -O2 -c -o src/Container.o -Iinclude -Isrc src/Container.cpp
g++ -fPIC -std=c++0x -g -O2 -c -o src/Store.o -Iinclude -Isrc src/Store.cpp
g++ -fPIC -std=c++0x -g -O2 -c -o src/StoreFactory.o -Iinclude -Isrc src/StoreFactory.cpp
g++ -fPIC -std=c++0x -g -O2 -c -o src/PartitionController.o -Iinclude -Isrc src/PartitionController.cpp
g++ -fPIC -std=c++0x -g -O2 -c -o src/Query.o -Iinclude -Isrc src/Query.cpp
g++ -fPIC -std=c++0x -g -O2 -c -o src/QueryAnalysisEntry.o -Iinclude -Isrc src/QueryAnalysisEntry.cpp
g++ -fPIC -std=c++0x -g -O2 -c -o src/RowKeyPredicate.o -Iinclude -Isrc src/RowKeyPredicate.cpp
g++ -fPIC -std=c++0x -g -O2 -c -o src/RowList.o -Iinclude -Isrc src/RowList.cpp
g++ -fPIC -std=c++0x -g -O2 -c -o src/RowSet.o -Iinclude -Isrc src/RowSet.cpp
g++ -fPIC -std=c++0x -g -O2 -c -o src/TimestampUtils.o -Iinclude -Isrc src/TimestampUtils.cpp
g++ -fPIC -std=c++0x -g -O2 -c -o src/Field.o -Iinclude -Isrc src/Field.cpp
g++ -fPIC -std=c++0x -g -O2 -c -o src/Util.o -Iinclude -Isrc src/Util.cpp
swig -DSWIGWORDSIZE64 -outdir . -o src/griddb_python.cxx -c++ -python src/griddb.i
g++ -fPIC -std=c++0x -g -O2 -c -o src/griddb_python.o -Iinclude -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/numpy/core/include src/griddb_python.cxx
src/griddb_python.cxx:3185:10: **fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory
 3185 | #include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~**
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:58: src/griddb_python.o] Error 1

Any Ideas?
I’ve tried to install numpy and pandas, via apt, but still get the same error.
$ sudo apt install  python3-numpy 
$ sudo apt install  python3-pandas 


After verifying the Makefile, I was able to pinpoint the issue. Line 17, shown below, retrieves a list of site packages and picks the first one.
NUMPY_FLAGS := $(shell python3 -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages()[0])")

Running the command python3 -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages()[0])" returns the following:
['/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.12/dist-packages']

However, in my WSL Ubuntu installation, there is no directory “dist-packages” under python3.12. That directory is under python3 and that’s what causes the error, as it tries to include “-I/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/numpy/core/include”.
The solution was to edit the Makefile and change line 17 to NUMPY_FLAGS := $(shell python3 -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages()[1])") so it would pick the second item on the list, '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', thus preventing  the error from happening.
